# jPlayer and Summernote not working well together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, summernote

I am using both JPlayer and Summernote in my app, for some reason I cannot type the letters `f`, `l`, `m`, or `p` in the summernote editor. How can I fix this or get around it? Anyone ever had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-keyBindings

Looks like jPlayer's keybindings are taking priority. Either rebind the keys for jPlayer or disable them on your jPlayer instance.